# cannot pickle '_mysql_connector.MySQL' object

Tags: python, mysql, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, mysql-connector

when i receiving statistics from RS485，i want to save it in my MySQL database at the same time，as well as draw a plot by the statistics.As the threading in python can not satisfy my demand of effeciency,so i want to use multiprocessing.But i got this problem.Can you help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GuZhangJianCe\shujukuchuanru2.py", line 296, in <module>
    p2.start()
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_mysql_connector.MySQL' object
```

Comment: Pickle has many limitations regarding what can be serialized and what cannot. Try using `dill` instead https://dill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: thanks a lot,I will have a try immediately!

Comment: You can also have each child process create its own connection. Try posting a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you would like more assistance.